# Erro xmlns jsf, configuracoes?

Tags: java, jsf

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao tentar compilar uma pagina xhtml, estou o usando os xmlns`s abaixo:

Elements with namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/html may not have attributes in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf. Namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf is intended for otherwise non-JSF-aware markup, such as  It is not valid to have < h:commandButton jsf:id="button" />

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

E recebo warnings quanto a :

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="form-control"
                                        id="selectOlhos" jsf:value="#{corpoController.corpo.corOlhos}">
                                        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Escolha" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Verdes Claros" itemValue="Verdes Claros"></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Verdes Escuros" itemValue="Verdes Escuros"></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Castanhos Claros" itemValue="Castanhos Claros"></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Castanhos Escuros" itemValue="Castanhos Escuros"></f:selectItem>
                                    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema esta nessa linha:

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="selectOlhos" jsf:value="#{corpoController.corpo.corOlhos}">
```

O certo é:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="selectOlhos" value="#{corpoController.corpo.corOlhos}">
```

Ou seja, isso "*jsf:value*" não é um elemento de selectOneMenu